# Long ago vs. Long back

Tags: word-choice

Is it wrong to say: "I had learnt that long back"?
Is it more apt to say "I had learnt that long ago"?

Comment: I've never heard the phrase used as "learnt that long back." The closest I've heard is "I learned that a long 'time' back/ago." Of the two choices, your second is better.

Comment: "a long time ago" or "long ago."  "*long back*" seems to be an Indian-English idiom in my observation.

Answer (score 3):

Using "long ago" is the correct (i.e. commonly heard) term. As seen in [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=long+ago%2Clong+back&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clong%20ago%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clong%20back%3B%2Cc0) Ngram, "long back" is extremely rare.

[image: Ngram of "long ago" versus "long back"]

That's not to say that there aren't some constructions where "long back" might be correct, but it's quite uncommon. As noted in the comments, the sentence "I learned that ***a*** long **time** back/ago" would be acceptable.